# Array is getting nil in Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `ViewController` where I display the items. I fetch the data and assign it to my model class `ProductData` property which is `itemArray` as follows.

**ViewController.m**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:PRODUCT_ALL_URL parameters:nil progress: nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) {
    if(responseObject != NULL) {
        ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]init];
        for ( id jsonItem in responseObject)
        {
            dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];
            [self.pElements addObject:dicItem];
        }

        // I can debug and see the itemArray is getting assigned
        dicItem.itemArray = pElements;
        [self categorySelection];
        [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) 

}];
```

**ProductData.m**

```
+(ProductData*) restaurantDataInstance {
    static ProductData *restaurantDataInstance;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!restaurantDataInstance){
            restaurantDataInstance = [[ProductData alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return restaurantDataInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
 if (self = [super init]) {
    if (!itemArray || !itemArray.count){
        itemArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
```

I am trying to access `itemArray` later as follows, but `itemArray` is nil. Even though I assign it in the `ViewController`. I wonder what I am missing.

**GlobalFunctions.m**

```
ProductData *restaurantData = [ProductData restaurantDataInstance];
// the following returns a nil;
NSLog(@"%@",restaurantData.itemArray);
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `pElements` ?

Comment: I initialize `pElements` in `ViewWillAppear` -` ViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending to set the `itemArray` to the singleton in the GET method, you need to actually set `dicItem` to the singleton:

```
if(responseObject != NULL) {
    for ( id jsonItem in responseObject)
    {
        ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];
        [self.pElements addObject:dicItem];
    }

    // I can debug and see the itemArray is getting assigned
    [ProductData restaurantDataInstance].itemArray = pElements;//HERE!
    [self categorySelection];
    [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

If you just call `ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]init];` you are creating a new instance every time.

That should do it.

Comment: What's the point of `ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData restaurantDataInstance];` ? That object will get discarded immediately, because it's re-alloc'd in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with your code. Is `ProductData` supposed to be a) a single record about a single product, or b) a database of all products? You seem to be trying to use it as both.

If a) it should not be singleton class.
If b) you should never manually alloc/init a singleton.

You seem to be initialising three totally separate instances of ProductData.

1. `ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]init];` this never gets used and is discarded immediately upon 2 below.
2. `dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];`
3. `restaurantDataInstance = [[ProductData alloc] init];` - this is looking at the singleton object.

`dicItem.itemArray = pElements;` - pElements is an array of `ProductData` objects. Did you intend to have an object of type `ProductData` that contains an array of `ProductData` objects?

Comment: yes, I intend to have `ProductData` type object that contains an array of `ProductData` objects. Do you think it is wrong or something might be better?

Answer (score 0):

Define a property in singleton class like

```
@property (non atomic, strong) NSMutlabeArray* itemArray;
```

then alloc init this array in appDelegate

```
applicationDidFinishLanchingWithOptions
```